# Tight bounds on the iterates of the Clenshaw algorithm for Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm trying to bound the iterates of [the Clenshaw algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw_algorithm) when applied to the Chebyshev series, related to a question I'm running into related to the stability of this algorithm. Recall that, for $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^d a_iT_i(x)$, where $T_i(x)$ is the $i$th Chebyshev polynomial, the Clenshaw algorithm is the recursion
$$
\begin{aligned}
b_{d+1}(x) &:= 0 \\
b_d(x) &:= a_d \\
b_k(x) &:= a_k + 2x\cdot b_{k+1}(x) - b_{k+2}(x) \text{ for all } k \in \{0,\ldots,d-1\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
A computation shows that $p(x) = \frac12(b_0(x) + b_2(x))$, so this iteration can be used to compute $p(x)$. I am interested in the iterate, which one can show is
$$
b_k(x) = \sum_{i=k}^d a_i U_{i-k}(x),
$$
where $U_i(x)$ is the $i$th Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. Suppose we only know that $p$ has degree $d$ and bounded sup norm, $\|p(x)\|_\infty := \max_{x \in [-1,1]} |p(x)| \leq 1$. I'd like to know the best bound on the sup norms for these polynomials, $\|b_k(x)\|_\infty$. Bounding naively using the coefficient bound $|a_i| \leq 1$ gives the inequality
$$
\|b_k(x)\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{(d-k+1)(d-k+2)}{2} \leq d^2.
$$
This is how this quantity is typically bounded, and I am curious whether this bound can be improved or whether this is tight. Testing small cases (up to $d = 6$) suggests that there might be an order-$d$ loss in this bound, and the correct bound is
$$
\|b_k(x)\|_{\infty} \stackrel{?}{\leq} d - k+1,
$$
which would be tight for the Chebyshev polynomial $p(x) = T_d(x)$.

This seems to be a natural question that arises when studying the Clenshaw algorithm, so I think it may be possible that such a result exists somewhere I don't know about, or that this result is straightforward manipulation from the bounds on $p(x)$. I haven't found anything close yet after looking for some time, though.

Comment: Update: we figured out how to prove this, losing a log factor. See Section 8 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.01492).